# Spectral projections, additivity

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $K$ be a positive operator on a Hilbert space $H$. $Q_1$ and $Q_2$ are projections such that $Q_1\perp Q_2$.  Is
$$ E^{Q_1K Q_1} (1,\infty) + E^{Q_2K Q_2} (1,\infty) =E^{Q_1K Q_1 +Q_2K Q_2} (1,\infty) $$
true?

$E$ is the spectral projection.

Comment: what is $E^{T}(1,\infty)$, is it related to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection-valued_measure ?

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily.  Here's a 2-dimensional counterexample: take $K=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 3\end{pmatrix}$, $Q_1=\begin{pmatrix} 1/2 & 1/2 \\ 1/2 & 1/2\end{pmatrix}$, and $Q_2=I-Q_1$.  Then you can easily calculate that $Q_1KQ_1=2Q_1$ and $Q_2KQ_2=2Q_2$, whereas $(Q_1+Q_2)K(Q_1+Q_2)=K$.  So the left-hand side of your equation is $Q_1+Q_2=I$, but the right-hand side is just $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$.  You can think about what's going on as that each of the $Q_i$ averages together the eigenvalues of $K$ to be greater than $1$, but the sum $Q_1+Q_2$ keeps the eigenvalues separate and so some of them stay below $1$.

Comment: THX, however, I made a mistake!

Comment: I have edited the question